# wi-fi connection drops and doesn't connect

Tags: wireless

Wi-fi connects and works for more or less 10 minutes, then it drops. Then I try to reconnect, Network Manager just shows "connecting" animation, and asks my password from time to time. This continues until I reload my wi-fi router, and then it works fine another 10 minutes. Please help me solve this.

```
$ uname -a
Linux meiro-eME730G 3.2.0-67-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 17:45:51 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
```

Sorry, haven't updated in a while.

I tried wi-fi with another device, and it's connection drops simultaneously and also refuses to connect. So, I guess this is not Ubuntu's fault, and probably not related to this site.

Comment: Please add output to your question. `uname -a`, `cat /etc/lsb-release`. What about others devices? They work ok with this Wi-Fi Router?

Comment: @c0rp done. Old ubuntu, same problem on multiple devices.

Comment: check that is your wi-fi router is working properly with another devices.
And try to reset your wifi by pressing black button on device

Comment: This continues until I reload my wi-fi router, and then it works fine another 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue a couple times, particularly where it repeatedly asks for the AP password.

If I reboot the router, all is well. Give that a shot.

Comment: This continues until I reload my wi-fi router, and then it works fine another 10 minutes.